# NdisoidRequest status returning success but packet filter not set

Tags: c, windows, kernel, device-driver, ndis

I am calling the NdisoidRequest from the protocol driver. I am using the Microsoft sample intermediate driver. After calling the oid request it is giving the pending status. Then when the mini port completes the request it is calling the protocol driver's RequestComplete function. In this function I am getting status as zero.

I used the ndiskd.mopen. There I see the adapters are not set with the packet filters. It is showing no flags are set.

Why is it behaving like this?

This behaviour I am observing when I am installing the intermediate driver. It is working fine if I disable and re-enable the physical adapter.